# Linux : How to check for a specified Line under home directory

Tags: linux

I am using Linux machiene , through putty .
I am inside  the home directory inside the Linux server that is

**/home/kiran**

```
06:15 AM kiran@plii-testserver$ pwd
/home/kiran
```

Inside my profile (directory ) I want to find this line below  in which file this particular line has been set

```
apache-maven-2.2.1/bin
```

( I have checked out .profile file but nothing is mentioned in that file )

Sorry I don't know what Linux version I am using also as I don't have the cat folder under the root to check .
(But When I did with `uname`, it displayed GNU Linux, don't know whether this is useful or not )

Thank you .

Comment: which file are you talking about?

Comment: I don't know what you mean either, but perhaps grepping that line does something for you (`grep -r apache-maven-2.2.1/bin' .`)? Or when searching for the path, grep for that (`grep -rE \\bPATH\\b .`)?

Comment: this line  apache-maven-2.2.1/bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
grep -i apache-maven-2.2.1/bin *
```

Hopefully it will give you a result.

Comment: Thank you , generally this should be done from the root directory or from my home directory path ??

Comment: Depends on where you suspect the file to be that contains this line. Searching from root directory will take longer and most probably require admin privileges. I would start searching in your home directory and maybe then in file system root.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find root-path-to-search -type f -execdir fgrep 'apache-maven-2.2.1/bin' {} \+
```